# Forge to upgrade Revit files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

i managed to make GitHub sample "forge-upgradefiles-revit" work thanks for the help by Autodesk Zhong Wu, about half of the Revit files works OK but another half have the following error, any clue what's wrong and how to fix it? thanks.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the report.txt file for the failed work item?

Comment: "status": "failedInstructions",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2021-09-24T11:44:04.1206759Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2021-09-24T11:44:04.3108891Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2021-09-24T11:44:05.4557357Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2021-09-24T11:49:20.3943736Z",
    "timeFinished": "2021-09-24T11:49:20.5087037Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 31629312
  },
  "id": "2bf7ff8aca1b4a8bbe674768156f4f2c"

Comment: "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/Cj6Fvbwt6B0NwXZjIf0UWRXpQWWr9ErL/2bf7ff8aca1b4a8bbe674768156f4f2c/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3JJJRIRY3&Expires=1632532444&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIEp6EC%2BDwL%2FNTF%2FTs7g%2FAvRoCLUxGK%2B%2B1byr7DScVwQpAiEAmBk2%2BL3W2YK66hgYHfZ3bhDAdWvTnWNTupRGqM%2Bb4UQqmwIIQxADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDBr6qeqlMm%2B46Lr2bSr4Ad7MX46oXxbvvHjFmJ7rOcQ%2Ba4999tdzX1tqG6cPAh18YgCB6C4Mqv97Dg775zP

Comment: %2FVZxHA65zZzmm%2FsrHkb%2BSLIzCl0Nmh9sgf6AoAL%2FByJrWS8dkzRI7CLwv0fG%2FMJeHEAJic7sHMdWfMumu57kxdRyIvkAB1Tf4YdB1At6pYcBcAg4X0Eypmv2Pa8lQc%2Bo%2Fj5Y%2F%2FshGyB5Kqjenzr%2F7E64ia0lYtY2iJ0kuCYjAw6OZKBo%2BseTzS7k1MEHcAy8NB72muceHMh8xC9kLjrwLKurJkWtXYaNXriA09Uu%2F%2BZk%2BHtsltYWj1ziorusyotzAWSAG%2FribNW0IMOXCtooGOpoB2NcK4qEMXcjYqpNs7WPvwfzFMwPT8%2Br9AfYIQAjHp8yO3q9qj9wggrH0cnQbMLJWviusBfI%2BbU2vCcAETz2OCfiH3T3YhsvIS6t2Mub%2BZgKHZmkTOuUNbR7bc0jdndRXUVbkuUMc%2BdMDKvyfyMa2qom15njK5EpmxRSe5ThJ8%2FuTSEltH67NhsIGZ2Z%2FQPJ0LRddftES9cSmjg%3D%3D&Signature=CBeGUMD7miNZrHtwoEg3U1SO1wQ%3D",

Comment: thanks Adam, sorry for pasting multiple times due to char length limit, have a great weekend!

Comment: Every time you get a URL to a report file, that times out pretty quick - i.e. I already cannot access it. Could you just upload the txt file here as part of your question or share it somewhere else?

Comment: thanks Adam, don't know how to upload report.txt here, i sent it to your autodesk email address, hope you don't mind

Comment: Let me reply you personally for the log file.

Comment: sure, thanks Zhong